# Split digit using regex python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape data from https://www.mygov.in/covid-19, using **Selenium**, but when I extract the digits, there raises a new problem. [image: image preview]. The number indicate current value and value of how much it changed. eg: 3,81,74,366⬆54,229.

When I scrape I get the text as 3,81,74,36654,229. So how can I get the current value only, using **Selenium Python** ?

eg:
3,81,74,36654,229 to 3,81,74,366
10,79,894198 to 10,79,894
22,40,7200 to 22,40,720

Comment: Could you post the scraping code? It might be easier to modify that than to try a regex on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extract of an HTML fragment from that page:

```
<p class="mid-wrap">8,43,56,092
  <span class="data-up">39,477</span>
</p>
```

If you get the text for the p element, the return value will be merged with the span content.

Consider doing this:

```
for p in soup.select('p.mid-wrap'):
    span = p.find('span')
    if span:
        spantext = span.getText()
        print(spantext)
        span.extract()
    print(p.getText())
```

**Output:**

```
39,477
8,43,56,092
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all numbers are bigger than one thousand and current value is the first thing in the string something like this should work

```
^.*?,\d{3}
```

Comment: @AnandhuH like I said it wont work for number lower than 1000 because it cant tell if its 6 116 or 61 16 or 611 6 for higher numbers you get a useful coma so you know exactly where the numbers end. If you need to support numbers lower than 1000 you need a different solution entirely.